# How to Install full featured ubuntu or debian on usb and use it anywhere?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb, 17.04, debian

I want to install full version of ubuntu or debian in my usb stick/portable hdd. My purpose is to keep my full featured linux with me (not the live one).

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? I create separate full install flash drives. My older ones are BIOS and newer are all UEFI. You do have to partition in advance and if UEFI use gpt and include the ESP - efi system partition. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu But even with BIOS, you can use gpt, but then need an unformatted bios_grub partition of 1 or 2MB. MAC similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/886528/why-did-ubuntu-16-04-2-install-the-loader-on-macbook-pro-hard-drive-despite-bein?noredirect=1#comment1384515_886528

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I was thinking that some of the computer may not support uefi so its safe to use legacy bios If I want to use it on any computer...

Comment: I am not saying that I want to install it on any pc just on my usb with bootloader  I am not getting what you told me to do...

Comment: A full install to a flash drive is just like any full install to a second drive. I prefer to partition in advance, but you need to use Something Else option which is the only option that lets you choose the external drive for the grub2 boot loader. Does not hightlight changing boot loader to sdb, if external drive, but shows other install screenshots:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-optiond